# docker-compose: node modules dependencies does not exist

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, cypress

##### What I'm trying to do

I'm trying to run my cypress tests in the Gitlab CI using docker-compose. I'm pulling down all my services (which is working all fine) within `docker-compose.yml` and then the last service is to run my cypress tests. I bring up all the services and run the tests executing command:

`docker-compose up --abort-on-container-exit --exit-code-from e2e`

I have a separate cypress project where all the tests, docker related files reside which is shown below

##### Issue I'm facing

When I run the `cypress run` command locally it works all fine but when I try to mimic the same on CI using `docker-compose` and `Dockerfile` it does not get the `node_modules` packages. The tests fail with an error like `Module not found: <package name>`. I have a theory that my Dockerfile is flawed. I might be mounting a volume erasing its original content idk.

My directory structure is:

```
.
├── config
├── cypress
├── .dockerignore
├── .gitlab-ci.yml
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── package-lock.json
└── package.json
```

My `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM cypress/browsers:node16.13.2-chrome97-ff96
WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN npm ci

RUN ls /app/node_modules <--- this shows all the devDependencies
```

I do not have `dependencies` within this project. Only `devDependencies`

My `docker-compose.yml`:

```
  ...

  e2e:
    image: cypress/browsers:node16.13.2-chrome97-ff96
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - web-app
    command: node folderExists.js <--- shows node_modules exists but the devDependencies folders are missing
    working_dir: /e2e
    volumes:
      - ./:/e2e
```

Since the devDependencies are missing, that seems like why my tests are not able to find the modules. But I have no idea how to fix it!

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your node_modules are installed under /app/node_modules, but you change the working directory to /e2e, so it expects to find the modules under /e2e/node_modules and they aren't there. Why do you change the working directory?

Comment: @HansKilian - Thanks for the reply. I initially had the `/e2e` on the Dockerfile, it didnt make any difference. I can try that again and update my question

Comment: Thanks @HansKilian - That seemed to have fixed the issue. I tried so many things I might have missed adding the `e2e` back when I got the other issues working. Thank you!

Comment: @HansKilian - worth mentioning, the code above **does not** work as-is. I had to create a volume and mount that for the node_modules to be available run time

Answer (score 0):

To get my code working I had to make **2** changes:

**First**, As @HansKilian mentioned in the comments, I was not using the right mounted working directory within Dockerfile. So updated `app` to `e2e` within Dockerfile.

This alone unfortuntately didn't fix the issue. I was still getting the `Error: Cannot find module 'cypress-cucumber-preprocessor'` error on CI.

**Second**, I had to create a volume (`docker volume create --name=nodemodules`) before `docker-compose up` command. Then mount that volume within my service. Im creating the volume within my `gitlab-ci.yml`.

So my `docker-compose.yml` now looks like:

```
  ...

  e2e:
    ...
    volumes:
      - nodemodules:/e2e/node_modules
      - ./:/e2e

volumes:
  nodemodules:
    external: true
```